# text process in python

Tags: python

I have data like this:

```
value1
something text
something text
```

And I want to change the something text with the value. Example:

```
value1
value1
value1
```

Comment: any way to identify which lines are "value" and which lines are "something" ?

Comment: `I have data like this:` Is that a text file? A string? A list....

Comment: Comedy one-line solution: `print (lambda lines: "\n".join([lines[max(i for i in [idx_ for idx_, line in enumerate(lines) if line.startswith("value")] if i <= idx)] for idx in range(len(lines))]))(open("input.txt","r").read().split("\n"))` Don't try this at home, kids.

Answer (score 1):

One way:

```
import sys

file = open('file','r')

for line in file:
    if line.startswith('value'):
        pattern=line
    sys.stdout.write(pattern)
```

Save the script to `script.py` and run it with `python script.py` *(where `script` is something descriptive)*.

```
value1
value1
value1
value2
value2
value3
value3
value3
value3
value3
```

And redirect the output `python script.py > new_file`

Answer (score 1):

```
with open('input.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

value = ''
with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
    for line in lines:
        if line.startswith('value'):
            value = line
        f.write(value)
```